# How can i disable a function, in XCode 8 swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, disabled-input

So i have made a quiz app and when the user completes the 10 questions it hides the buttons and shows a button to go to the next one. I have recently added a countdown timer to it and it works but when they finish the test the timer continues and i want to find a way to disable it when they finish the quiz. So they don't get taken to the try again page when they already completed it. Hope it makes sense!

Update timer code

```
internal func updateTimer()
{

    counter = counter - 1
    if(counter > 0)
    {
        ibCounter.text = String(counter)
    }else{   
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue13", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Timer code.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(cricketTest1View.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

This is the part where i put in code for when the user finishes the quiz

```
func PickQuestion(){

        if Questions.count > 0{
            QNumber = 0
            QuestionLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

            AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

            for i in 0..<Buttons.count{

                Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState())

            }

            Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
        }
        else{

            QuestionLabel.text = "YOU HAVE COMPLETED THE QUIZ"
            Button1.isHidden = true
            Button2.isHidden = true
            Button3.isHidden = true
            Button4.isHidden = true
            NextQuiz.isHidden = false
            Start.isHidden = true
            ibCounter.isHidden = true
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `timer.invalidate()` when your quiz completes.

It should be put in your else part as per your code.

Comment: Yep just did, i didn't realise it was there until now!

Comment: @Seth Not a problem , upvote it also,if you want . You have not upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Right below these lines that indicate the quiz has been finished, you want to stop the timer:

```
    QuestionLabel.text = "YOU HAVE COMPLETED THE QUIZ"
    Button1.isHidden = true
    Button2.isHidden = true
    Button3.isHidden = true
    Button4.isHidden = true
    NextQuiz.isHidden = false
    Start.isHidden = true
    ibCounter.isHidden = true
```

If you looked at Timer's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer), you will find a method called [`invalidate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate):

> Stops the timer from ever firing again and requests its removal from its run loop.

This is the exact method you need to call:

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Comment: @Seth if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: Just did, i didn't realise that there was a button there until now!